# Showing Game Center high scores in UILabels

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

I'm making a turn based iPhone game with a maximum of 2 players, in my game You can get a score which will be put in a Game center leaderboard. The next time you start the game up your highest score will be retrieved and you can make it even higher because the app counts on from that previous highscore. I found some code to get the authenticated players score But I also wanna show the score of the opponent you are playing and I was wondering how?

This is the code I found for the authenticated player (yourself)

```
 if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID, nil];
GKLeaderboard *board = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:arr];
if(board != nil) {
    board.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    board.range = NSMakeRange(1, 1);
    board.category = @"MY_LEADERBOARD";
    [board loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving score.", nil);
        }
        if (scores != nil) {
            NSLog(@"My Score: %i", ((GKScore*)[scores objectAtIndex:0]).value);
        }
    }];
}
[board release];
[arr release];
}
```

is there a way to modify this so it will show what I want?
Also I have a problem showing NSLog(@"My Score: %i", ((GKScore*)[scores objectAtIndex:0]).value);
in a UILabel :S

Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"My Score: %lld", ((GKScore*)[scores objectAtIndex:0]).value);

the score values are 64bit integers, not int's

intValue
longValue
longLongValue  <<==